# Facing such problem like no model name edge tpu found and no module name edgeTPU_cpp_wrapper

Tags: deep-learning, google-coral, edge-tpu

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_edgetpu_cpp_wrapper', [dirname(**file**)])
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 296, in find_module
raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_edgetpu_cpp_wrapper'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/DeepPiCar/models/object_detection/code/coco_object_detection.py", line 9, in <module>
import edgetpu.detection.engine
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/edgetpu/detection/engine.py", line 17, in <module>
from edgetpu.basic.basic_engine import BasicEngine
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/edgetpu/basic/basic_engine.py", line 17, in <module>
from edgetpu.swig.edgetpu_cpp_wrapper import BasicEnginePythonWrapper
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 28, in <module>
_edgetpu_cpp_wrapper = swig_import_helper()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/edgetpu/swig/edgetpu_cpp_wrapper.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
import _edgetpu_cpp_wrapper
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_edgetpu_cpp_wrapper'

Tyring to open up object detection program through edgeTPU. ERROR !! NO Module Found.

Answer (score 0):

[Edge TPU API](https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu) is deprecated. Please modify your code/project to work with [pycoral API](https://github.com/google-coral/pycoral/releases)